# Can someone please solve this limit?

Tags: limits, trigonometry

> $$\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1 - \cos 2\pi x}{x^2}$$

You can swap this identity $\cos(2x)=(\cos(x))^2-(\sin(x))^2$.
You can also switch the $1$ but what after that? I'm lost there.

Comment: limit of what...?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. What limit? That's a trigonometric identity. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: That is not a limit, It is an identity.... and I don't see anything to solve.

Comment: I'm new here, not sure why the link didn't appear.

Comment: hint: the Taylor series expansion for $\cos(x)=1-\frac{x^2}{2!}+O(x^2) $

Comment: If you know L'Hopital's rule, try applying it twice.

Comment: We haven't gotten to Hopital's rule yet, This question is from a previous generation's partial exam, i'm currently studying for mine but looks like they got further with their studies than we have.

Comment: @BojanVelkoski Personally, the only two approaches that I would consider for this problem are either L'Hopital's Rule or Taylor series expansion, both of which have already been suggested in the comments.  If those two approaches are excluded, then I would have considered the problem as requiring that I (somehow) **re-invent the wheel**.  In my experience, this is generally a bad idea in any math courses below the post-graduate level.  Far better to insist on getting proper training on how to attack a specific math problem before trying to attack the math problem.

Comment: @BojanVelkoski Are you permitted the limit $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} = 1$?

Comment: Yes, @TheoBendit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\bbox[pink]{\text{The first method.}}$

We will use here **L'Hopital's rule**, because our limit has a look $\left[\frac{0}{0}\right]$, therefore,
$$
\lim_{x\to{0}}\frac{(1-\cos2\pi{x})^{'}}{(x^{2})^{'}}=\lim_{x\to{0}}\frac{2\pi\sin(2\pi{x})}{2x}.
$$
After the first differentiation our limit has a look $\left[\frac{0}{0}\right]$ again, therefore, we must get the second derivative, using **L'Hopital's rule**, mentioned above:
$$
\lim_{x\to{0}}\frac{(\pi\sin(2\pi{x}))^{'}}{x^{'}}=\lim_{x\to{0}}(2{\pi}^{2}\cos(2\pi{x}))=2{\pi}^{2}.
$$
After the twice using differentiation we will receive:
$$
\bbox[lightgreen]
{
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1 - \cos 2\pi x}{x^2}=2{\pi}^{2}
}.
$$

---

$\bbox[pink]{\text{The second method.}}$

$$
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1 - \cos 2\pi x}{x^2},
\\
\cos(2x)=\cos^{2}(x)-\sin^{2}(x),
\\
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1 - \cos 2\pi x}{x^2}=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1 - \cos^{2}\pi{x}+\sin^{2}\pi{x}}{x^2}=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{2\sin^{2}\pi{x}}{x^2}.
$$
We know the famous formula $\bbox[yellow]{\lim_{x\to{0}} \frac{\sin(x)}{x}=1}$, therefore,
$$
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{2\sin^{2}\pi{x}}{x^2}\cdot\frac{\pi^{2}}{\pi^{2}}=\lim_{x \to 0} \left(2\pi^{2}\cdot\frac{\sin\pi{x}}{x}\cdot\frac{\sin\pi{x}}{x}\right)=2\pi^{2}.
$$
$$
\bbox[lightgreen]
{
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{1 - \cos 2\pi x}{x^2}=2{\pi}^{2}
}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

another approach is:
$$
1-\cos(2 \pi {x}) = \cos(0) - \cos(2\pi x) = 2\sin^2(\pi{x})
$$
Then, with this, yo can perform:
$$
\frac{2\sin^2(\pi{x})}{(\pi{x})^2}\pi^2\rightarrow {2\pi^{2}}.
$$