# I'm not sure if I'm solving this continous limit properly

Tags: limits

This is the function  $f(x)=|x-1|,\; x < -1$

By this $x$ belongs in the interval $(-\infty,-1) $

Let $c \in (-\infty, -1)$

$1^\circ f(c)=|x-1|=-c+1$

$2^\circ \lim_{x \to c^+} f(x)$ has  to exist

$\lim_{x\to c^+}f(x)=\lim_{x\to c^+}|x-1|=|\lim_{x\to c^+}(x-1)|=|c-1|=-c+1$
I'm not sure if the last step where I leave the absolute value is correct.

If it is then:

$3^\circ \lim_{x \to c^+}f(x)=f(c)$

And the function is continuous in the interval $(-\infty, -1).$

I greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: Hey @bojan. Notice your $f$ function is a composite of two continuous function. So by definition $f$ is continuous.

Comment: @user264745 This argument works, but it is not by definition!

Comment: @Zuy Yeah. You’re right. One need to prove a theorem before using the statement of the theorem.

Comment: @user264745 yeah you're right, didn't notice it until you pointed it out. But i think i'm supposed to prove it here by showing that f(c)=limit f(x)

Comment: @Bojan Velkoski, How is about the reference https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4310103/can-someone-please-solve-this-limit? Do you like the solutions of your problem (first and second methods)?

Comment: @VadimChernetsov I just accepted it, your answer was really well structured. The second method was what i needed because we haven't yet learned Hopital's rule.

Comment: @Bojan Velkoski, Good luck!

Comment: Can someone please point me in the right direction for learning absolute value when it comes to limits. Most of what i've seen is where $\lim_{x \to c^+}$ c is defined as a number.